# How to show the JSON data into dynamic input text fields?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, ajax

I have a JSON data coming through AJAX GET method is:The JsonData is stored in `var trDataSecondTable` and displayed when I did `console.log(trDataSecondTable)`.

```
{  
   "assessCatAmount":[  
      {  
         "assessmentNo":1,
         "assessmentType":"PRE",
         "assessCatId":1,
         "assessReason":"A",
         "assessAmount":1,
         "assessPenalty":2,
         "entryBy":"PCS",
         "rStatus":"1"
      },
      {  
         "assessmentNo":1,
         "assessmentType":"PRE",
         "assessCatId":1,
         "assessReason":"D",
         "assessAmount":3,
         "assessPenalty":4,
         "entryBy":"PCS",
         "rStatus":"1"
      },
      {  
         "assessmentNo":1,
         "assessmentType":"PRE",
         "assessCatId":2,
         "assessReason":"B",
         "assessAmount":5,
         "assessPenalty":6,
         "entryBy":"PCS",
         "rStatus":"1"
      },
      {  
         "assessmentNo":1,
         "assessmentType":"PRE",
         "assessCatId":2,
         "assessReason":"E",
         "assessAmount":7,
         "assessPenalty":8,
         "entryBy":"PCS",
         "rStatus":"1"
      },
      {  
         "assessmentNo":1,
         "assessmentType":"PRE",
         "assessCatId":3,
         "assessReason":"C",
         "assessAmount":9,
         "assessPenalty":10,
         "entryBy":"PCS",
         "rStatus":"1"
      },
      {  
         "assessmentNo":1,
         "assessmentType":"PRE",
         "assessCatId":3,
         "assessReason":"F",
         "assessAmount":10,
         "assessPenalty":10,
         "entryBy":"PCS",
         "rStatus":"1"
      }
   ]
}
```

My form looks like this which is dynamic type (can be added by clicking "+" or can be deleted by pressing "-")

My form when page is loaded first looks like :

[image]

**I need to show these six JSON data into this form.If there is three JSON data then there should be three row total along with data.If there is twelve json data then twelve row needs to appear along with data in input field.**

```js
 function sumIt() {
  $("#formContainer [type=number]").each(function() {
    var $row = $(this).closest(".row");
    var $fields = $row.find("[type=number]");
    var val1 = $fields.eq(0).val();
    var val2 = $fields.eq(1).val();
    var tot = (isNaN(val1) ? 0 : +val1) + (isNaN(val2) ? 0 : +val2)
    $row.find(".sum").text(tot);
  });
  var total = 0;
  $(".sum").each(function() {
    total += isNaN($(this).text()) ? 0 : +$(this).text()
  });
  $("#tot").text(total);
  return total;
}

$(".customs-table .remove:lt(1)").hide();  
$(".vat-table     .remove:lt(1)").hide();  
$(".excise-table  .remove:lt(1)").hide();  

$("#formContainer").on("click", "button", function() {
  var selector = "div.row";
  var $div = $(this).closest(selector);
  if ($(this).is(".add")) {
    var $newDiv = $div.clone();
    $newDiv.find(":input").val(""); // clear all
    $newDiv.find("[type=number]").val(0); // clear numbers
    $newDiv.find(".sum").text(0); // clear total
    $newDiv.insertAfter($div)
  }
  else {
    $div.remove();
     sumIt(); 
  }
  $(".customs-table .remove:gt(0)").show();  
  $(".vat-table     .remove:gt(0)").show();  
  $(".excise-table  .remove:gt(0)").show();  
});


$("#formContainer").on("input", "[type=number]", sumIt);

$("form").submit(function() {
  event.preventDefault();
  var user_profile = [];
  $(".row").each(function() {
    var $fields = $(this).find(":input");
    if ($fields.length > 0) {
      var cat = $(this).find("div>label").eq(0).text(); // use the label of the row
      var catId = ["","Customs","VAT","Excise"].indexOf(cat)
      user_profile.push({
        assessmentType: "PRE",
        assessCatID : catId, 
        assessReason: $fields.eq(0).val(),
        assessAmount: $fields.eq(1).val(),
        assessPenalty: $fields.eq(2).val(),
        assessTotal: +$fields.eq(1).val() + +$fields.eq(2).val() // the leading + makes it a number
      });
    }
  });
  console.log(user_profile);
  
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<form id="myForm">
  <div id="formContainer" class="col-md-12" style="float: none;">
    <!--  <button onclick="myFunction()" class="pull-right">+</button> -->
    <div style="margin-bottom: 30px;">
      <div class="form-group row">
        <div class="col-md-1"></div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <label>Reason</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
          <label>Amount</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
          <label>Penalty</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-1">Total</div>
        <div class="col-md-2">Action</div>
      </div>
      <div class="customs-table row">
        <div class="col-md-1">
          <label>Customs</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <input type="text" class="form-control customReason" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
          <input type="number" class="form-control txt customAmount" value="0" name="abc" min="0" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
          <input type="number" class="form-control txt customPenalty" value="0" name="abc" min="0" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-1">
          <span class="sum">0</span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
          <button type="button" class="add">+</button>
          <button type="button" class="remove">-</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="vat-table row">
        <div class="col-md-1">
          <label>VAT</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <input type="text" class="form-control vatReason" name="vatReason" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
          <input type="number" class="form-control txt1 vatAmount" value="0" name="vatAmount" min="0" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
          <input type="number" class="form-control txt1 vatPenalty" value="0" name="vatPenalty" min="0" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-1">
          <span class="sum">0</span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
          <button type="button" class="add">+</button>
          <button type="button" class="remove">-</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="excise-table row">
        <div class="col-md-1">
          <label>Excise</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <input type="text" class="form-control exciseReason" name="exciseReason" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
          <input type="number" class="form-control txt2 exciseAmount" value="0" name="exciseAmount" min="0" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
          <input type="number" class="form-control txt2 excisePenalty" value="0" name="excisePenalty" min="0" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-1">
          <span class="sum">0</span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
          <button type="button" class="add">+</button>
          <button type="button" class="remove">-</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-12 pull-right">
        <label>Total:</label>&nbsp;<b><span id="tot">0</span></b>
      </div>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success pull-right">Submit</button>
  </div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

I tried to manipulate using the for loop but not able to show them into those dynamic field.How can i achieve this?

Updated Code:

Since there are customs,vats,excise i need their each number like 1,2.Each of their start with 1,2,3 so on. 
[image]

So here is what i try:
i added `customNo` class.

```
<div class="col-md-1 customNo">
            <label>Customs</label>
          </div>
```

and to show 1,2,3 i declared 3 different variable.

```
var showEmpty=true;
  var i=1,j=1,k=1;
  $.each(data.assessCatAmount, function(_,cat) {
    showEmpty = false; // there was data
    var type = types[cat.assessCatId];
    var $newDiv = $("#formContainer").find("."+type+"-table").eq(0).clone(); 
    $.each(cat,function(key,value) {
    $(".customNo").append("<div><label for="name"> i </label></div>");
       var fieldName = key.replace("assess",type);
       var $field = $newDiv.find("."+fieldName);
       if ($field) $field.val(value);
       i=i+1;
    });
    $("#formContainer").append($newDiv)
```

So i tried   `$(".customNo").append("<div><label for="name"> i </label></div>");` it is not displaying me 1,2. How can i get this?

Comment: it i snot clear what exactly you want to show

Comment: i want to show that coming json data into the dynamic input fields. The input field needs to be loaded with data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to copy the clone part

```
var types = ["","customs","vat","excise"]; // 1,2,3 must match class names
$.each(data.assessCatAmount, function(_,cat) {
  var type = types[cat.assessCatId];
  var $newDiv = $("#formContainer").find("."+type+"-table").eq(0).clone(); // clone the FIRST one
  $.each(cat,function(key,value) {
     var fieldName = key.replace("assess",type);
     var $field = $newDiv.find("."+fieldName);
     if ($field) $field.val(value);
  });
  $("#formContainer").append($newDiv)
});
```

You may need to hide or fill the first 3 divs since I do not fill them, I only use them to clone from

Also move the total to the bottom like I did with the submit

```js
var types = ["", "customs", "vat", "excise"]; // 1,2,3
function getText(str) {
  return $.trim(/\s/.test(str)?str.split(/\s+/)[1]:str);

}
var data = {
  "assessCatAmount": [{
      "assessmentNo": 1,
      "assessmentType": "PRE",
      "assessCatId": 1,
      "assessReason": "A",
      "assessAmount": 1,
      "assessPenalty": 2,
      "entryBy": "PCS",
      "rStatus": "1"
    },
    {
      "assessmentNo": 1,
      "assessmentType": "PRE",
      "assessCatId": 1,
      "assessReason": "D",
      "assessAmount": 3,
      "assessPenalty": 4,
      "entryBy": "PCS",
      "rStatus": "1"
    },
    {
      "assessmentNo": 1,
      "assessmentType": "PRE",
      "assessCatId": 2,
      "assessReason": "B",
      "assessAmount": 5,
      "assessPenalty": 6,
      "entryBy": "PCS",
      "rStatus": "1"
    },
    {
      "assessmentNo": 1,
      "assessmentType": "PRE",
      "assessCatId": 2,
      "assessReason": "E",
      "assessAmount": 7,
      "assessPenalty": 8,
      "entryBy": "PCS",
      "rStatus": "1"
    },
    {
      "assessmentNo": 1,
      "assessmentType": "PRE",
      "assessCatId": 3,
      "assessReason": "C",
      "assessAmount": 9,
      "assessPenalty": 10,
      "entryBy": "PCS",
      "rStatus": "1"
    },
    {
      "assessmentNo": 1,
      "assessmentType": "PRE",
      "assessCatId": 3,
      "assessReason": "F",
      "assessAmount": 10,
      "assessPenalty": 10,
      "entryBy": "PCS",
      "rStatus": "1"
    }
  ]
}


function sumIt() {
  $("#formContainer [type=number]").each(function() {
    var $row = $(this).closest(".row");
    var $fields = $row.find("[type=number]");
    var val1 = $fields.eq(0).val();
    var val2 = $fields.eq(1).val();
    var tot = (isNaN(val1) ? 0 : +val1) + (isNaN(val2) ? 0 : +val2)
    $row.find(".sum").text(tot);
  });
  var total = 0;
  $(".sum").each(function() {
    total += isNaN($(this).text()) ? 0 : +$(this).text()
  });
  $("#tot").text(total);
  return total;
}

// data={} // test no data
function addNums(i) {
  $(this).html(function() {
    var text = $(this).text();
    // Get the text without leading number - fake a space in case there are none yet
    var type = getText(text);
    var length = $("."+type.toLowerCase()+"-table").length;
    return (length===1?"":i+ "&nbsp;") + type; // only show numbers if more than one
  });
}


function cleanUp() {
  $(".customs-table .remove:gt(0)").show();
  $(".vat-table     .remove:gt(0)").show();
  $(".excise-table  .remove:gt(0)").show();

  $(".customs-table.row > div > label").each(addNums);
  $(".vat-table.row > div > label").each(addNums);
  $(".excise-table.row > div > label").each(addNums);

}


$(function() {

  $(".customs-table .remove:lt(1)").hide();
  $(".vat-table     .remove:lt(1)").hide();
  $(".excise-table  .remove:lt(1)").hide();

  $("#formContainer").on("click", "button", function() {
    var selector = "div.row";
    var $div = $(this).closest(selector);
    if ($(this).is(".add")) {
      var $newDiv = $div.clone();
      $newDiv.find(":input").val(""); // clear all
      $newDiv.find("[type=number]").val(0); // clear numbers
      $newDiv.find(".sum").text(0); // clear total
      $newDiv.insertAfter($div)
    } else {
      $div.remove();
      sumIt();
    }
    cleanUp();
  });


  $("#formContainer").on("input", "[type=number]", sumIt);

  $("form").submit(function() {
    event.preventDefault();
    var user_profile = [];
    $(".row:visible").each(function() {
      var $fields = $(this).find(":input");
      if ($fields.length > 0) {
        var cat = getText($(this).find("div>label").eq(0).text()); // use the label of the row
        var catId = types.indexOf(cat.toLowerCase())
        user_profile.push({
          assessmentType: "PRE",
          assessCatID: catId,
          assessReason: $fields.eq(0).val(),
          assessAmount: $fields.eq(1).val(),
          assessPenalty: $fields.eq(2).val(),
          assessTotal: +$fields.eq(1).val() + +$fields.eq(2).val() // the leading + makes it a number
        });
      }
    });
    console.log(user_profile);
  });

  var showEmpty = true;
  $.each(data.assessCatAmount, function(_, cat) {
    showEmpty = false; // there was data
    var type = types[cat.assessCatId];
    var $newDiv = $("#formContainer").find("." + type + "-table").eq(0).clone();
    $.each(cat, function(key, value) {
      var fieldName = key.replace("assess", type);
      var $field = $newDiv.find("." + fieldName);
      if ($field) $field.val(value);
    });
    $("#formContainer").append($newDiv)
  });
  $(".customs-table").eq(0).toggle(showEmpty);
  $(".vat-table").eq(0).toggle(showEmpty);
  $(".excise-table").eq(0).toggle(showEmpty);
  cleanUp();
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title></title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <form id="myForm">
    <div id="formContainer" class="col-md-12" style="float: none;">
      <!--  <button onclick="myFunction()" class="pull-right">+</button> -->
      <div style="margin-bottom: 30px;">
        <div class="form-group row">
          <div class="col-md-1"></div>
          <div class="col-md-4">
            <label>Reason</label>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-2">
            <label>Amount</label>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-2">
            <label>Penalty</label>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-1">Total</div>
          <div class="col-md-2">Action</div>
        </div>
        <div class="customs-table row">
          <div class="col-md-1">
            <label>Customs</label>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-4">
            <input type="text" class="form-control customsReason" />
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-2">
            <input type="number" class="form-control txt customsAmount" value="0" name="abc" min="0" />
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-2">
            <input type="number" class="form-control txt customsPenalty" value="0" name="abc" min="0" />
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-1">
            <span class="sum">0</span>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-2">
            <button type="button" class="add">+</button>
            <button type="button" class="remove">-</button>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="vat-table row">
          <div class="col-md-1">
            <label>VAT</label>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-4">
            <input type="text" class="form-control vatReason" name="vatReason" />
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-2">
            <input type="number" class="form-control txt1 vatAmount" value="0" name="vatAmount" min="0" />
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-2">
            <input type="number" class="form-control txt1 vatPenalty" value="0" name="vatPenalty" min="0" />
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-1">
            <span class="sum">0</span>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-2">
            <button type="button" class="add">+</button>
            <button type="button" class="remove">-</button>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="excise-table row">
          <div class="col-md-1">
            <label>Excise</label>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-4">
            <input type="text" class="form-control exciseReason" name="exciseReason" />
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-2">
            <input type="number" class="form-control txt2 exciseAmount" value="0" name="exciseAmount" min="0" />
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-2">
            <input type="number" class="form-control txt2 excisePenalty" value="0" name="excisePenalty" min="0" />
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-1">
            <span class="sum">0</span>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-2">
            <button type="button" class="add">+</button>
            <button type="button" class="remove">-</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12 pull-right">
      <label>Total:</label>&nbsp;<b><span id="tot">0</span></b>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success pull-right">Submit</button>
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: sir i need a litttlle help from you please see the updated code sir

Comment: sir is there any way to show those number in left hand side like 1.Customs as it is appearing in right hand side.Sorry for the change.

Comment: sir but when i click the  "+" button it is showing me 2.1.  3.2.1. like this error

Comment: sir its ok that i dont need to change the ordering number, but the assessCatID is all becoming -1 when i click submit button. Why is this change happening?

Comment: sir i tried your method but it says $(...).find(...).split is not a functi . Its ok sir you can help me after christmas :)

Comment: what to fill in the blank sir?

Comment: if ($fields.length > 0) {

        var catStrings = $(this).find("div>label").split(/\s+/)
        var cat = catStrings.length==1?catStrings[0]:catStrings[1]
    
      } sir i added these codes inside the if block and it is still showing me the same error $(...).find(...).split is not a function

Comment: ok sir i will contact you after christmas.Merry christmas sir :)

Comment: sir if you are free please help me to manipulate them ,if you are busy its ok

Comment: assessCatId is all coming -1 it should be 1,2,3

Comment: Numbering system is correct , there is no problem. But when I run your code at snippet and when i click submit button assessCatId of that JSON field  is all going -1 as it should be 1,2,3 according to customs,vat,excise. I mean to say that

Comment: but while submitting 9 data are going to json where in form we have 6 data

Comment: Changed to `$(".row:visible").each(function() {`

Comment: ok sir i will send you the money after my project is completed :).happy new year

Comment: Only if you can - I never request this, but you changed specs so many times that I worked for more than an hour on this

Comment: sir i added   $(".customs-table .remove:lt(0)").hide();
  $(".vat-table     .remove:lt(0)").hide();
  $(".excise-table  .remove:lt(0)").hide();
    to hide the "-" button when page is loaded.But it is not working.Is there any solution sir?